# sqlite manager lookup table

Tags: sqlite, lookup-tables

Does anyone know how to use a lookup table to find IP addresses in sql?

In sqlite manager, I have a lookup table, **country_ip**, that has the ranges of IP addresses, variables **start** and **end**, and a variable with the corresponding **country**. The IP was converted into an integer. In another table, **simple_english**, I have the actual IP address as an integer, **ip_convert**. How in sql can I take the IP address ip_convert and search the ranges in the other table to find the country, and then populate the former table? I can't seem to figure it out. I was thinking of coding something like:

```
update simple_english
set simple_english.country = country_ip.country 
from simple_english, country_ip

where simple_english.ip_convert
BETWEEN country_ip.start AND country_ip.end 
from simple_english, country_ip;
```

But, I'll welcome any suggestions. Thanks!

Tom